# Regex.replace() not working after appending child

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a basic mad lib style code using Regex and I am unable to create new input elements and have them behave like the initial one.

I've tried swapping out (doc.replace(regex[i]... for (doc.replace(inputArray[i]... - this works partially, but in the end I am stuck with brackets around the input value.

```
<!-- HTML
<div id = "doc" contentEditable="true">{input1} {input2}</div>
<div id = "inputs">
<input type = "text" id = "input1"> {input1}
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
<button onclick="addInput()">Add Input</button>
</div>
-->

//Global Variables
var inputNumber = 1;
var regex = [/{input1}/g];
var inputArray = ["input1"];

//Generate
function generate(){
for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
var doc = document.getElementById("doc").innerHTML;
var outputArray = document.getElementById(inputArray[i]).value;
document.getElementById("doc").innerHTML = (doc.replace(regex[i], outputArray))
};
};

//Add Input
function addInput(){
    inputNumber++;
    var inputs = document.getElementById("inputs");
    var newInput = document.createElement("div");
    newInput.innerHTML = "<p><input type='text' id='input"+inputNumber+"'> {input"+inputNumber+"}</p>";
    inputs.appendChild(newInput);
    inputArray.push("input"+inputNumber);
    regex.push("/{input"+inputNumber+"}/g")
};
```

I want {input2} to become the value of the input with the id of 'input2' when the function generate() is called. It just straight up doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use regex to extract information from HTML.  Use DOM methods with CSS selectors.  You can load that HTML text as a document fragment and query it using DOM methods, just like you can with content in the page.

Comment: Without using regex, how can I target all inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my code snippet for test.

```js
//Global Variables
// RegEx save input
var regexInputs = /\{(input\d+)\}/g;

//Generate
function generate(){
  var doc = document.getElementById("doc");
  var inputs = doc.innerHTML.matchAll(regexInputs);
  var input = inputs.next();
  while(input.value){
    doc.innerHTML = doc.innerHTML.replace(
      input.value[0], document.getElementById(input.value[1]).value);

    input = inputs.next();
  };
}

function addInput(){
  var inputs = document.getElementById("inputs");
  var idxInput = inputs.children.length + 1;
  var newInput = document.createElement("div");
  newInput.innerHTML = "<p><input type='text' id='input"+ idxInput +"'> {input"+ idxInput +"}</p>";
  inputs.appendChild(newInput);
}
```

```html
<div id = "doc" contentEditable="true">{input1} {input2}</div>
<div id = "inputs">
  <input type = "text" id = "input1"> {input1}
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
<button onclick="addInput()">Add Input</button>
</div>


<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Notes:
The regexInputs is the pattern that match all inputs and store (input\d+), so using matchAll we go througth all matches.
Every match has two index 0 has "{input#}" and 1 has "input#". With this strings we just do replaces.